# Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ArrayBinding.elementsType()" because "arrayBinding" is null

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, spring-tool-suite, m2eclipse

I'm using SpringToolSuite:

Version: 4.16.1.RELEASE
Build Id: 202210240748
Revision: 4e8e5b4a7f22310c0505603e0659a2b7083aaffb

Together with m2e

Eclipse.org - m2e   M2E Maven Integration for Eclipse Core  2.1.2.20221130-2239 org.eclipse.m2e.feature

And since last update(s) ... since today ... I got for all my projects this error:

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'rest-service'.
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ArrayBinding.elementsType()" because "arrayBinding" is null

Here are the details from eclips error-log-view:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ArrayBinding.elementsType()" because "arrayBinding" is null
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.codegen.CodeStream.newArray(CodeStream.java:6656)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.codegen.TypeAnnotationCodeStream.newArray(TypeAnnotationCodeStream.java:87)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ArrayInitializer.generateCode(ArrayInitializer.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ArrayInitializer.generateCode(ArrayInitializer.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ReturnStatement.generateCode(ReturnStatement.java:232)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.generateCode(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:355)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.generateCode(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:292)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.generateCode(TypeDeclaration.java:761)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.generateCode(TypeDeclaration.java:824)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.generateCode(TypeDeclaration.java:754)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.generateCode(TypeDeclaration.java:831)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.generateCode(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:412)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:916)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ProcessTaskManager.run(ProcessTaskManager.java:145)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
```

I opened an m2e issue ... mabye a the end its not related to m2e ... but just for sharing ... https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/1111

Comment: Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, copy it and paste it into your question, formatted as _Code Sample_. It sounds something uses internal stuff from Eclipse JDT which might have changed. You can revert updates in _Help > About Eclipse IDE: Installation Details: Installation History_.

Comment: I tried to go back to a previous version already ... but no luck ... "old" versions are no longer existing ... just error for rolling back eclipse updates. I think this whole update-mechanism is broken since years :)

Comment: Please provide the full details from the error log, not only the stack trace. How can that with which you had "no luck" be reproduced? So, you updated today, but the whole update-mechanism is broken for you since years? If the update-mechanism doesn't work for you, you should fix that first, e.g. by do a fresh installation.

Comment: Eclipse update process hell is another topic :) Was not the cause here.

Comment: The Eclipse update process works like a charm for me and others. The problem is that Lombok uses internal staff (`org.eclipse.jdt.internal...`) rather than public API. According to your reported Lombok issue you run Eclipse with Java 19. Better use the latest Java with long term support, which is currently Java 17. Nowadays, new Java versions are no longer 100% backward compatible.

Answer (score 0):

OMG ... the real reason was total different :)

The internal eclipse compiler error was because of a lombok annotation, which was suggested by eclipse (sonarlint maybe? or lombok? no glue) ... But when I add the @Default annotation to the array field ... eclipse crash :-O

[image]

I repored a lombok issue: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3306